# Whats the single proper word for spelling mistakes are done for style?

Tags: single-word-requests

Whats the single proper word for spelling mistakes are done for style?

- Spider = Spyder
- Crack = krack
- Creation = kreation
- Cat = kat
- Inglorious  basterds  = Inglourious Basterds

Comment: It's on the tip of my tongue....

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Is that answer?

Comment: No, i meant i knew the word but ive forgotten now

Comment: "bast**a**rds" is the correct spelling.

Comment: 'Sensational spelling'.

Comment: Define ***mistake***

Comment: It's not a spelling mistake if it's done on purpose. I agree with Edwin's suggestion, I've heard that term before.